# How can I get neo4j to connect to local demo?

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j installed (& the conf file says that authentication is off.)
I start the movie demo --- and am told to connect to the server.
When I type
:server connect
with No Authentication
the browser tells me that there is a graph waiting for me but then gives the message "Unable to extract host form undefined."

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to run the movie demo, you might prefer to use the free Neo4j sandbox rather than Neo4j Desktop. It runs in a web browser and there is nothing to install.
https://sandbox.neo4j.com/

If you prefer to use Neo4j Desktop, confirm that your database has started.
https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2018/03/20/neo4j-undefined-unable-to-extract-host-from-undefined/